# Flutter: How to make a sequence of http requests on a widget before build method

Tags: flutter, dart

I have 3 classes: Users, Posts and Comments. **User** has many **Posts** and
**Posts** has many **Comments**.

I want that all data to be fetched before the widget's build method is called.

I tryed to use **initState()** to do this:

```
class FetchDataExample extends StatefulWidget {
  final User _user;

  FetchDataExample(this._user);

  @override
  _State createState() => _State(_user);
}

class _State extends State<FetchDataExample> {
  final User _user;

  _State(this._user);

  @override
  void initState() {
    _user.setPosts();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    print(this._user.posts[0]);


    return Container(

    );
  }
}
```

In **User class**  I have:

```
void setPosts() async {

    String url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts?userId=' + this.id.toString();
    var request = Requester.get(url); // Returns a Future<Response>

    await request.then((value) => this.posts = Post.jsonToPosts(json.decode(value.body)));

    this.posts.forEach((post) => post.setComments());

    print(this.posts[0]);
}
```

The 'setComments()' has the same logic.

I have two prints:

1. Inside **build** that returns **null**;
2. Inside **setPosts** the returns **Instance of 'Post'**;

So, by the time that Build method is called in the widget, the initState has not finished yet.

I need it be finished, does anyone know how can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `FutureBuilder` to build a widget by using latest result from a future.
And also you can combile multiple futures into a single one using `Future.wait` method.

Here is a sample code:

```
_getPageData() async {
  var _combinedFutures =  await Future.wait([setPosts, setComments]);
  //do stuff with data
}
...
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
         future:_getPageData(),
         builder: (context, snapshot) {
            return Container();
         }),
    );

  });
```

Comment: HasilT, I need to do about 4-5 different requests that uses previous requests values, and nesting so many FutureBuilders don't seems like a good practice. 

Also, using 'Future.wait' I imagine that I can't get a Post's Id to search the comments related to that post. Right?